# How to Add Border in export excel

Tags: c#, excel

I need to download listview as excel file. I am using the following code

```
 public static void ExportListViewAsExcel(Page currentPage, ListView lstviewControlId, string excelName)
    {
        string str = "attachment; filename=" + excelName + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_tt") + ".xls";
        currentPage.Response.ClearContent();
        currentPage.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", str);
        currentPage.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter writer2 = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
        HtmlForm child = new HtmlForm();
        lstviewControlId.Parent.Controls.Add(child);
        child.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
        child.Controls.Add(lstviewControlId);
        child.RenderControl(writer2);
        currentPage.Response.Write(writer.ToString());
        currentPage.Response.End();
    }
```

Its export successfully. But while open it, it doesnot contain border. Its fully white background.

1. I need Border.
2. Also Set Width and Height of the Row.
3. I have 16 digit bank account number before with Zero. It shows scientific. I    need to show this as it is 16 digit Number before with 0.

   How to achieve it. Help me

Comment: You are not creating an Excel file you are creating an HTML file with an Excel extension that Excel happens to be able to open.  Try your luck modifying the HTML as per your needs and see if Excel will honour it or generate a proper Excel file .